can nohup and disown both still let program run after exiting the shell
I'm discovering the difference between nohup and disown in Ubuntu's bash.
I have while.py.
import time
while True:
    print(1)
    time.sleep(1)

First, I used ssh to connect to my ubuntu server and entered nohup python3 while.py &. Then I entered exit to exit the terminal. After I reconnected to the server and entered ps aux | grep python, I could clearly see the process running. Then I kill this process.
Second, I entered python3 while.py & disown. The program began to print 1 in the shell. Then I exited the shell and reconnected to the server. However, when I typed ps aux | grep python, I couldn't see the process running.
It seems that disown didn't prevent the process being killed after closing the terminal. I have searched for the relative problems. celtschk mentions that disown make sure the shell won't send it a SIGHUP and nohup make sure the process won't receive any sent SIGHUP. This answer mentions that the terminal sends SIGHUP, SIGCONT, SIGCHID to all processes when closed. Thus I have a question why nohup and disown behave differently after closing the terminal.
English is not my mother tongue. Forgive me if exists grammar mistakes. I would greatly appreciate it if you could help.

I've discovered the problem's reason. This answer mentions that

if the terminal is destroyed (which can happen if it was a pty, like those created by xterm or ssh, and the controlling program is terminated, by closing the xterm or terminating the SSH connection), the program will fail as soon as it tries to read from standard input or write to standard output.

After the terminal exits, disown doesn't disconnect to stdout or stderr. My program print(1), which tries to write to stdout and causes the program to crash.
To solve the problem, we just need to redirect stdout and stderr by python3 while.py >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown

In the original hardware environment of unix, the "terminal" was a piece of hardware attached to a serial port.  This could be an actual terminal or a modem on a phone line or something similar.
If you called the modem with your remote modem and connected, you would then log into the system.  When you disconnected ("hang up") the system would send a HUP to everything connected to the serial port.  The system would then send the HUP signal (see man -s 7 signal) to every process connected to that serial port to clear them out and make the port available to the next user.  If you logged out of a physical terminal, this would also simulate a hangup.
Serial ports still exist, but most "terminals" are now virtual, implemented in software, and connected through the pseudo terminal (pty) interface.  But this still acts nearly identically to a serial port.  Pseudo terminals have two interfaces -- a master interface which the terminal software connects to, and a client side that acts like the software side of an external serial port.
When the master pty is closed (maybe by closing the window, or disconnecting ssh) or any number of other actions occur, this triggers the same events that a modem hangup would trigger, sending a HUP signal to every process connected to the terminal.
The nohup command blocks the HUP signal from being received by the process so it won't be directly killed.  However, it may still have stdin and stdout connected to the terminal.  After the master pty is closed, stdin and stdout will be effectively replaced with /dev/null which may cause the process to receive an EOF on stdin if it tries to read, which may still cause it to exit.
If a shell has background jobs and you exit the shell, it will typically try to kill the jobs it knows about with the HUP signal to clean up after itself.  The disown command tells the shell to forget about a job in its job control list.  But this does not disassociate the processes in the job from the terminal which may still try to get rid of them.

Thanks for the detailed explanation. I've discovered the problem that the program tried to write to standard output, but the terminal is terminated so that the program will crash.

If you write to stdout you may get a HUP or EPIPE.  If you redirect to /dev/null in addition to nohup, this problem should go away.

disown removes the process from the shell's job control, the process will still be attached to the terminal session - so when you exit the terminal the process will die.

Hi, thanks for your answer. Can you explain further on "so when you exit the terminal the process will die"? man bash mentions the shell sent SIGHUP to all children processes but disown prevents the shell from sending a SIGHUP signal to the specific jobs. As a result, the process will not be killed. I'm confused on why the process is killed when the terminal is exited. What happens under the hood?
